# Reducing database operation time Django/ Mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

So, the thing is I am having a moderately large list of emails ~ 250,000 entries.

I have another table containing list of invalid emails ~ 50,000 which i need to remove (mark inactive) from 1st table. For that I have ran a simple django function which is taking 3-4 seconds in each loop. The code is:

```
def clean_list():
    id = 9
    while id<40000:
        i = Invalid.objects.get(id=id)
        y = i.email.strip()
        f = IndiList.objects.get(email__contains=y)
        f.active = False
        f.save()
        id +=1
```

What would be a better way to do it? Either a SQL query or a better piece of django code or some other way.

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested:

```
IndiList.objects.filter(email__in=Invalid.objects.only('email').all()).update(active=False)
```

I am not sure if Django is smart enough to build a subquery from that, if not, then this should do:

```
IndiList.objects.filter(email__in=Invalid.objects.all().values_list('email', flat=True)).update(active=False)
```

The problem with the second approach is that it will generate 2 queries instead of one, and inject 50,000 ids into the second sql query string, so I would much rather just use raw sql at this point:

```
from django.db import connection

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute = 'UPDATE indilist SET active=false WHERE email IN (SELECT email FROM invalid)'
```

Comment: Exactly, Raw SQL is way faster.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple optimisations you might want to take a look at. Instead of looping over a get for each object try getting a values list:

`queryset = Invalid.objects.filter(id__range=(9,40000))
queryset_list = queryset.values_list('email' flat=True)`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#values-list

then looping over the values list and doing a .get() on the email. At the end you can also do:

`f.active = False
f.save(update_fields=['active'])`

Which will only update the boolean field.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#updating-attributes-based-on-existing-fields

Also try to find a way to .get() the object via id or some other field than string if possible.

Answer (score 0):

After a few iterations, i used this function which was more than **1000 times faster.**

```
def clean_list3():
    pp = Invalid.objects.filter(id__gte=9)
    listd = [oo.email.strip() for oo in pp]
    for e in IndiList.objects.all():
        if e.email.strip() in listd:
            e.active=False
            e.save()
            print(e.id)
```

The trick is simple, instead of hitting database every time, I saved the 250,000 objects in a queryset in memory. and also the list of emails from invalid list in memory.

And then i had to hit database only when we found matching emails so as to save it as inactive.